# Switch Statement javaScript

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

This is the question:

> After your prompt, add a switch statement that will test for several different cases (that is, different possible user inputs). Create as many as you like! (Do at least three.) Don't forget to include a default block at the end that will provide a response if the user's choice doesn't match one of your cases.

This is my code:

```
var user = prompt ("Can you compelete the task?").toLowerCase();
switch (the ninja stopped you from moving forward) { 
  case 'fight': 
    console.log("Are you strong enough" && "smart enough");       
    break; 

  case 'run':
    console.log("Are you fast enough outrun the ninja");
    break;

  case 'pay':
    console.log("Can you afford to pay the ninja");
     break;

  default:
    console.log("or will you be defeated by the ninja");
};
```

This is the error I get I went over the code but can't find the error sorry in advance I'm a very new programmer thanks for the help in advance.

SyntaxError: missing ) after switch expression

Comment: What do you expect "`the ninja stopped you from moving forward`" to do? That's not valid syntax which is why you're getting your syntax error.

Comment: What are those words supposed to mean in your switch statement? That's just a sentence; it's supposed to be an expression.

Comment: Here is the [MDN's guide to JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide). I suggest you start reading, because you seem fundamentally lost.

Comment: You must replace `switch (the ninja ... forward) {` by `switch (user) {`.

Comment: Lot's of down votes. This question is quite well asked, it contains everything needed to provide an answer. The fact that it's a very basic issue should not be the reason for down votes.

Answer (score 2):

Your switch condition:

```
the ninja stopped you from moving forward
```

Is not valid syntax.  Even if you defined all those variables, you'd still get an error. Use a real condition in your switch:

```
var a = "1";
switch(a){
    case 1:
        console.log("Hello");
        break;
    default:
        console.log("Foobar");
}
```